# Is the MediaCodec-MediaExtractor combo necessary for video scrubbing in Android?

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec

I'm implementing a slider that lets me choose the frame I want to save as an image, and as everyone probably knows, the `seekTo()` function of Android's default `MediaPlayer` sucks - it doesn't actually seek to the closest frame to the timestamp, but to the closest I-frame, meaning the sought-after frame can be off by as much as a few seconds.

That's why I'm considering making a custom `MediaPlayer` implementation that uses `MediaCodec` and `MediaExtractor`. Are they necessary for exact seeking?

Answer (score 1):

Use ExoPlayer instead, it will save you time and headache.

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

If you still want to make your own video player, 
`MediaExtractor` can not do the accurate seek (in fact it should not seek to frame other than I frame, since decoding can only starts from I frame)

So what you should do is seek to previous I frame using `MediaExtractor` and start decoding frame from  that point using `MediaCodec` ( you can discard the result ) until you reach your desired frame.